# How to use webpack with download jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, node-modules

Downloaded the minified versions of `jQuery` and `jQuery_cookie`. Trying to use `webpack` on them, but getting an error:

> ERROR in ./src/js/jquery_cookie.js
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery' in 'C:\Users\MSI-PC\Documents\code_site\server2\src\js'
> @ ./src/js/jquery_cookie.js 11:2-29
> @ ./src/js/index.js

**index.js :**

```
require('./jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
require('./jquery_cookie.js');
```

**Site:**

```
node_modules/
dist/
public/
src/
   css/
   ejs/
   js/
      index.js
      jquery-3.2.1.min.js
      jquery_cookie.js
server.js
package.js
webpack.config.js
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = { 
    entry: './src/js/index.js',    
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {publicPath: '/dist/'},  
    module: {
        rules: [{test: /\.ejs$/,
                 use: ['ejs-loader']}]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/ejs/index.ejs',
            minify: {collapseWhitespace: true}
        })
    ]
}
```

Already tested with `ìmport jquery from './jquery-3.2.1.min.js'` but it didn't work.

Also tested to insert into `jquery_cookie` in to the root of jQuery, but that didn't work too.

The last thing tried was to add this `window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");` into my `index.js`, but that also failed.

#### Edit

Edit to add news informations. Tested to install jquery `npm install jquery` and to require him into my `index.js`. Getting no error when I started webpack. But my other API like `semantic-ui`, `jQuery-ui` and others files `.js` that use jQuery didn't work. My console return error :

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js:14:3
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined semantic.min.js:11:1
ReferenceError: $ is not defined client.js:96
```

Also tested with insert into `webpack.config.js` a loader `expose-loader` but also failed :

```
test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'jQuery'
                },{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: '$'
                }]
```

with plugin :

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",  
            jQuery: "jquery" 
        })
```

Comment: Share webpack config please.

Comment: Done to add webpack config

Comment: What exactly are you using jquery for?  Typically you can simpling run the npm install command to get jquery if you want to import it into your files.

Comment: Already tested it but after I will get the problem to export ``jQuery`` globaly. I don't know how to manage that. I tested with ``expose-loader`` but jQuery didn't find by any of my page or API that need it...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need webpack to make use of jquery. Just use a `script` tag and point to your library.

The best place to insert it is before the end of your `body` tag.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Read more: https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: Currently, it is the way I use jquery. But I want to limit my ``script`` tag. So, what I need to do to solve my problem ?

Comment: If thats the case then check Egor answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js#L14

`jquery_cookie` is trying to `require('jquery')`, but you don't have one in `node_modules`. You should install it:

`npm i jquery`

This error should no longer appear.

P.S. There can probably be a solution using `webpack`'s `resolve.alias` or something similar in order to use your file while requesting `require('jquery')`, but I don't see a reason for not doing regular `npm install` in favor of a locally downloaded `jquery` file. Not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that didn't work. I edited my question to improve it.